# In which cases is % not interpreted as a begin comment delimiter?

Tags: listings, comments

Today I encountered for the first time the `lstlisting` environment. I noticed that, in this environment, the `%` char is not interpreted as a "begin comment delimiter" and this broke my "clear-comment" script.

My question is: are there other cases in which the `%` char is not interpreted as a comment char?

MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{listings}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}

%% No comment here!

\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Well, in any other case in which the `\catcode` of the `%` character has been changed…  Do you know what `\catcode`s are?

Comment: @GuM, Yes, I know what `\catcode`s are. I meant others known cases that have the same behaviour.

Comment: I apologize, I didn’t mean to belittle your knowledge of TeX.  What I was trying to suggest is that there is little point in trying to catch all possible cases in which a `%` sign doesn’t start a true comment.  Not even the `docstrip` utility tries to do so.

Comment: If the `%` is proceeded by a backslash, the `%` does not being a comment.

Comment: Perhaps this question aims for a list of all verbatim environments, but as GuM mentions, this list will never be complete, because you can always define new such environments

Comment: Besides the verbatim cases, a percent sign does not start a comment if it is proceeded by the same two characters of category code 7.

Comment: @siracusa a list of all commonly used (not locally defined) verbatim enviroments would be indeed a god enhancement for my purpose.

Comment: @yudai-nkt If somebody's keyboard has a malfunctioning `e` key, typing `^^%` is indeed a solution. `;-)`

Comment: @GabrieleNicolardi I'm afraid that the answer is “whenever it isn't a comment character”. In normal documents (with a not so broad definition of “normal”), the places to watch for are `\verb`, `verbatim`, `lstlisting` or similar environments, but also URLs as argument to `\url` or related `hyperref` commands.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In verbatim like commands and environments, `%` prints as itself, so `verbatim`, `\verb` and  `filecontents` in the standard format or popular packages such as `listings` which provides `lstlistings` and `\lstinline` or `minted` which provides `minted`, `\mint` and `\mintinline` also `fancyverb` package which defined several environments including `Verbatim`.

More specialist uses include the `doc` package where `%` is ignored in the main text (but treated verbatim in `macrocode` environments), or the `url` or `hyperref` packages where `%` is allowed in `\url` if used at the top level.

So without using any packages or explicit `\catcode`

```
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.txt}
 50% of this is nonsense
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\b^^%gin{^^%numerate}
\it^^%m  some text\index{aa%bb}  more t^^%xt,
\item \verb|x%y|  and \verb*|x%y|.
\item
\begin{verbatim}
aa % yyy
\end{verbatim}
\item
\begin{verbatim*}
aa % yyy
\end{verbatim*}
\end{enumerat^^%}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This is very helpful! I'll wait a couple of day for further hints before accept your answer.